# How to bring the extension to google chrome apps page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shortcut-file

I am using google-chrome (version-69) in Ubuntu 18.04. I want to create a desktop shortcut for `Google-keep` extension. I followed the help from [How to Install Google Keep Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic GNU/Linux](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2018/02/07/how-to-install-google-keep-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-gnulinux/). According to the above link, one has to `right-click` the extension that appears on the link `chrome://apps/` in my chrome browser. But some of the extensions which I installed in the chrome do not appear in the link `chrome://apps/`. So, how to make the extensions appear in the `chrome://apps/` page?

Comment: Only chrome apps can appear there. Extensions aren't apps so they can't be there. There's nothing you can do about it AFAIK.

Comment: @wOxxOm Isn't Google-keep chrome app.

Comment: As noted in its title it's "Google Keep Chrome Extension", and its manifest.json has no `app` section.

Comment: @wOxxOm but the link which is in my question shows the google keep in apps page

Comment: Well, that probably means Google is playing dirty again and forcefully shows some of the extensions there that were previously apps like Google Keep.

Comment: @wOxxOm is there a way I could make a shoutcut for google keep in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Technically there should be no way. I don't know why that article says it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the extension to an App instead, and it will display under the apps section of chrome. If you look at the chrome web store, the Apps and Extensions are separated from each other. You can only choose one or the other, not both. Google does not offer the choice of being able to do both at once. However, if you really wanted to, with few code modifications you can add an extension and app under two slightly different names and use both.